# Calculator Class error checking

Tags: java, string, parsing

I'm doing some error checking for my BigInteger Calculator class. If an input has a space in between numbers and no valid operator (+,-,*,/,%,^) in between those numbers like the one below it is supposed to return "Error". Is there any way to check for this case using string methods?

Should return error because there is space in between numbers and no operator in between them:

> 2 + 1 1 1 1 1 + 2 //in this case the 1's do not have operators in between
>
> 2 2 2 //has spaces in between

valid:

> 2 + 2
>
> 22 + 2 + 1
>
> 2 + 11111 + 2

Comment: Pattern matching could do the job for you. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to split the string using `String[] temp = [stringName].split(" ");` and check to see that every other index is a valid operator.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use regex to find space in between numbers.

```
String input = "1+2 2 2";
boolean found = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+\\s+[0-9]+").matcher(input).find();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to find the space between numbers specifically. In fact you should be ignoring spaces completely other than as delimiting the tokens.

You just need to scan and parse according to a grammar that doesn't have a syntax for two consecutive numbers. Or operators. At any given point you should know what's expected and what isn't.